# Scrape data using spanID in R

Tags: r

Scraping error using span ID

I have been successfully able to login to a website. I want to scrape the post status if it's delivered or not. This is wrapped inside a Span ID "lblFinalStatus" which i am unable to scrape with the following code

```
library(rvest)

url <-"http://203.115.106.5/PodTrackingnew/PodTracking.aspx"
pgsession <-html_session(url)

pgform   <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(pgform, "txtPodNo" = "EM3352650")

submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)

memberlist <-jump_to(pgsession,"http://203.115.106.5/PodTrackingnew/PodTracking.aspx")

page <- read_html(memberlist)


#Error
usernames <- html_nodes(page,"#lblFinalStatus")
```

I want to obtain "Packet of Mr./Ms./M/S. KISHAN HARISHANKAR SHARMA is Delivered" statement from the website in the usernames variable above.

Comment: I see a submit form in the response.

Comment: yes so it doesn't actually login even after supplying "txtPodNo"